# How does one make sense of a string of logical comparisons?

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators

For example, how would one make sense of `(true && false || (53 < 24));`?
I'm aware that it evaluated to false I'm just curious as to how I would figure that out step by step.
Thanks!

Comment: Same as with **any** Java expression.  1) Apply operator precedence rules.  2) Evaluate operands of and operator left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check a handy [Java Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) table, which shows that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, meaning that the expression is equivalent to:

```java
((true && false) || (53 < 24))
```

Then you start evaluating:

```java
((true && false) || (53 < 24))
        ↓
(     false      || (53 < 24))
                        ↓
(     false      ||   false  )
                 ↓
               false
```

Comment: I think the *seemingly* random precedence is what tripped me up a bit. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @CaliCrunch Most people can't remember all the precedences, which is why you check a handy table that is remembering for you. A simple web search for [`java operator precedence`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+operator+precedence) will easily lead you to one. The one at [Princeton](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) is actually better than the one I linked to in the answer, since it shows the extra level 16, and it shows the Associativity.